# Is it possible to set a minimum connections count for HTTP Client pool?

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient, pool

I would like to known if it is possible to somehow specify the minimum number of connections for a pool that the system will strive to maintain on an ongoing basis?

For connection limiting I use `MaxConnectionsPerServer` property and it works fine, but I can't find something like `MinConnectionsPerServer`

Here is a code snippet for better understanding:

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpClient>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100,
        PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1),
        PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)
    })
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

Comment: Why? What problem do you expect this will solve?

Comment: `PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1),` - as far as I understand this can lead to problems with DNS changes. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#dns-behavior) for more info.

Comment: Creating a connection takes a lot of time. If the HttpClient needs to process a large number of requests at one time, this often leads to timeouts. It is more reliable to have many open connections at the start and not waste time establishing new ones

Comment: The DNS is not an issue for me since I use IP instead